# Is there any code for finding a certain keyword in twitter

Tags: python, twitter, twitterapi-python

I was wondering if anyone has any sample code for finding a certain keyword in twitter that has been recently posted and has a certain amount of likes within a certain timeframe
preferably in python. Anything related to this would help a lot if you have it. Thank You!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I haven't tried much yet. That's why I want some sample code to see the general process and stuff so I can write my own code on it, I honestly don't know howto do this.

Comment: Did you at least obtain a Python library for the Twitter API? If so, did you try reading any of its documentation?

Comment: ok I'll do that. Sorry, I'm new to coding and I only know a little bit about it.

Answer (score 1):

I have personally not done this before, but a simple google search yielded this (a python wrapper for the Twitter API):

https://python-twitter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

and a GitHub with examples that they linked from their getting started page:

https://github.com/bear/python-twitter/tree/master/examples

There you can find some example code for getting all of a user's tweets and much more.

Iterating through a list of users tweets might be able to do the job here, but if that doesn't cut it I recommend searching the docs linked above for what you need.